# Redirect /7A/url to /fps/7A/url

Tags: html, .htaccess, redirect

I want to redirect any URL or text after /7A.

So `example.com/7A/testpage.php` or `example.com/7A/folder/`
would redirect to:
`example.com/fps/7A/testpage.php` or `example.com/fps/7A/folder`

Would this be possible using .htaccess or even PHP?
Would you use RedirectMatch in .htaccess?
I tried something like this:

```
RedirectMatch ^/7A/$ /fps/7A/$1?
```

but I'm pretty sure it won't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
Redirect /7A /fps/7A
```

This will redirect anything that starts with `/7A` to the same path but starting with `/fps/7A`

Comment: Thank you! It was that simple!